# Handling permissions of multiple apps in django using django-rest-framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am building an ERP API with `django 1.11` + `python3` + `django_rest_framework`

I have the following apps that in my django project:

1. `Accounts`: To handle user profiles and authentication
2. `HR`: To manage employees
3. `Payroll`: To manage for payroll management

I would like to implement permissions across the application. I have been looking at different ways of implementing this but I need advice.

How I can make user permissions across multiple apps?

I would also appreciate if you provide useful resources related to this.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have to implement your custom permission and use it wherever you want. 
DRF documentation has good examples.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

If you want to apply your custom permission across all of your apps, specify 
in the settings

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
   'myapp.permissions.MyCustomPermission',
)
```

In this case, DRF will be check your permission in every view.